# Unable to load gif on Glide

Tags: android, android-glide

I want to load reddit gifs via glide on my Android app.

But it's throwing Error reading data from stream error. But that url works fine.

Here is the error log

Error reading data from stream

> java.io.InterruptedIOException: thread interrupted
>                                                                     at com.android.okhttp.okio.Timeout.throwIfReached(Timeout.java:145)
>                                                                     at com.android.okhttp.okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:133)
>                                                                     at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:211)
>                                                                     at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:50)
>                                                                     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$FixedLengthSource.read(HttpConnection.java:418)
>                                                                     at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read(RealBufferedSource.java:371)
>                                                                     at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
>                                                                     at com.bumptech.glide.util.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:65)
>                                                                     at com.bumptech.glide.util.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:60)
>                                                                     at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.RecyclableBufferedInputStream.fillbuf(RecyclableBufferedInputStream.java:132)
>                                                                     at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.RecyclableBufferedInputStream.read(RecyclableBufferedInputStream.java:309)
>                                                                     at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
>                                                                     at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.gif.GifResourceDecoder.inputStreamToBytes(GifResourceDecoder.java:105)
>                                                                     at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.gif.GifResourceDecoder.decode(GifResourceDecoder.java:57)
>                                                                     at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.gif.GifResourceDecoder.decode(GifResourceDecoder.java:26)
>                                                                     at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.gifbitmap.GifBitmapWrapperResourceDecoder.decodeGifWrapper(GifBitmapWrapperResourceDecoder.java:101)
>                                                                     at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.gifbitmap.GifBitmapWrapperResourceDecoder.decodeStream(GifBitmapWrapperResourceDecoder.java:87)
>                                                                     at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.gifbitmap.GifBitmapWrapperResourceDecoder.decode(GifBitmapWrapperResourceDecoder.java:71)
>                                                                     at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.gifbitmap.GifBitmapWrapperResourceDecoder.decode(GifBitmapWrapperResourceDecoder.java:61)
>                                                                     at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.gifbitmap.GifBitmapWrapperResourceDecoder.decode(GifBitmapWrapperResourceDecoder.java:22)
>                                                                     at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeFromSourceData(DecodeJob.java:190)
>                                                                     at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeSource(DecodeJob.java:177)
>                                                                     at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeFromSource(DecodeJob.java:128)
>                                                                     at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.EngineRunnable.decodeFromSource(EngineRunnable.java:122)
>                                                                     at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.EngineRunnable.decode(EngineRunnable.java:101)
>                                                                     at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.EngineRunnable.run(EngineRunnable.java:58)
>                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
>                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>                                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
>                                                                     at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.FifoPriorityThreadPoolExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(FifoPr

Reddit GIF [url example](https://g.redditmedia.com/LeI6e0H_WR6oWhwVqawNrKeVt88ob0scp6lqqXvNMa8.gif?s=5d181d551a693b6ecf74e9afd58bfc36) :

GLide code to load gif

```
GlideDrawableImageViewTarget imageViewPreview2 = new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(holder.image);
      Glide.with(c).load(data.getImage()).listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                     @Override
                        public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {

                                     return false;
                                            }

                                 @Override
                                    public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                      return false;
                                            }
                                        }).fitCenter().into(imageViewPreview2);
```

Thanx for the help